# alternative of CIM authorized.net

Tags: cakephp-2.0, authorize.net

I have a website(PHP) which has payment functionality with recuring/autopayment feature where user will enter their credit card detail once for shopping and from next time onward they don't need to enter their credit card detail again. Credit Card detail will not be saved to my database but will be saved in payment gateway with unique id/reference. I just need to use reference id for payment whenever user do shpping.

Earlier, i was using authorize.net payment gateway with its CIM(Customer Information Management) feature for auto payment which was working fine but now my client does want this payment gateway. I want some alternate payment gateway which support CIM feature.

If someone has already done same kind of stuff then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Authorized.net is the best option, because of reputation, costs and developer friendly environment. However there are alternatives as stripe, 2checkout, braintree...